# Intercepting dynamic assignment of class attributes in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python class that exposes my numerical experiments to my analysis and post-processing routines. I use that class in my analysis and it works well since it exposes convenient functionality that I need for 99% of analysis. Occasionally, for some analysis, I have to extend its functionality with new capabilities, so in my Jupyter notebook I do:

```
def new_capability(self, stuff):
    pass

ExpClass.new_capability = new_capability
```

This way in that notebook, corresponding to that analysis, all instances of my `ExpClass` object in the notebook have access to that method and on any instance `e = ExpClass()` I can call `e.new_capability()`. And through all this I did not need to modify my class directly, which is what I want.

I am looking for a way to record all the new functions that I am dynamically assigning to a class this way. So my attempt to do this was:

```
ExpClass.newattrs = []

def seta(self, attr, val):
    ExpClass.newattrs.append(attr)
    object.__setattr__(self, attr, val)

ExpClass.__setattr__ = seta
```

My hope was that now if I do `ExpClass.new_capability = new_capability` then the value of `ExpClass.newattrs` would be `['new_capability']`. However, this is not working out. I realize this only works on instances of the class but not on the class itself. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: You should do it on the *class of the class*, i.e. the metaclass. Although be careful, you are getting into the arcana of attribute resolution on metaclasses which IIRC has some special behavior sometimes, but maybe this would suffice. Honestly, this seems like you should just create your class to accept the analysis function as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: Or add a class method that you use to register your new method, which also updates `newattrs`.

Comment: Why are you looking for a way to record all the new functions that I am dynamically assigning to a class this way?  If you want all of the functionality recorded centrally couldn't you just add the new capabilities to your base class?

Comment: @barny Could you provide me with a sample of how to do that? I tried by adding this to my class:
    @classmethod
    def registerFunction(cls, name, func):
        setattr(cls, name, func)
but then when I register a function I cannot access `self` in the newly registered function.

Comment: @JeffUK This is more for documentation in the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it appears to me that passing the function to constructor would only impact an instance, but I want the whole class to have the facility. I would also run into the issue about `self` which I ran into while implementing barny's solution.